# Simplify product of cosh and sech expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I would like to simplify a product of hyperbolic cosine and hyperbolic secant functions, with the key simplifying assumption being that the two are inverses of each other. This sounds like a silly thing to do, but I have some complicated integrals that won't evaluate unless these expressions simplify properly. If I do the following:

```
Simplify[Cosh[x]^(1/q)*Sech[x]^(2 + 1/q), 
 Assumptions -> q \[Element] Integers && q > 1]
```

I would naively expect to get $\text{sech}^2(x)$ as the simplified expression. However, Mathematica is unable to simplify this expression further. What additional assumptions do I need to make in order to get this simplification to go through?

Comment: You would get $sech^2(x)$ with the expression `Cosh[x]^(1/q)*Sech[x]^(2 + 1/q)` (note the `+` sign). However, Mathematica does not seem to simplify this either.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some values of `x` and `q` your assertion is not true

```
Cosh[x]^(1/q)*Sech[x]^(2 - 1/q) == Sech[x]^2 /.{q->2,x->3I}
(*False*)
```

Comment: Hm, so it seems like I can get the simplification to go through if I assume x is real. This is unusual because in the integral that this expression is a part of, x is integrated over the real axis, so I would have thought that this assumption would have been made. Perhaps the overall problem is different than what I had thought.

Comment: @HenryShackleton - When doing the integral did you use the option `GenerateConditions -> True`?

Comment: @HenryShackleton Of course! I missed that: if x is complex, then cosh(x) may vanish, and the simplified expression is not exactly equivalent. Substitute `x -> I Pi/2` for instance.